# Multiple Choice Quiz with Scoring and image output

Tags: html, css, scoring, multiple-choice

So I am having issues creating a scoring system that will take my users inpiut and place them into a category of a fake fan, hardcore fan, etc.

I had to repost this question, because it was closed. hopefully this post is more clear

this is for a project that is due tonight, and i am completely lost. these are the requirements:

"Take in and store user input from ten different questions answered by the user via HTML form elements
Use an array of options to correlate user data to a matrix of potential results 
Dynamically display appropriate result images and text to the user after completing the questions
Format appropriately for use on a mobile, tablet, or desktop screen using media queries"

this is the code i have so far

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Demi Quiz</title>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  .col {
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 46%;
  }
  .one {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .two {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .three {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .four {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .five {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .six {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .seven {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .eight {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .nine {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .ten {
    background-color: black;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col {
      float: none;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    h1 {
      color: red;
      text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<body>
  <form>
    <h1>How Big Of A Demi Lovato Fan Are You?<h1>
    
     <div class="col one">
     <br>
     1. Who did Demi punch back in 2010?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="one" id="manager" value="Wannabe"> <label for="manager">Manager</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="one" id="costar" value="Lowkey"> <label for="costar">CoStar</label>
         <br><input type="radio" name="one" id="father" value="Fake"> <label for="father">Father</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="one" id="dancer" value="Hardcore"> <label for="dancer">Dancer</label> 
     </div>
    
     <div class="col two">
     <br>
     2. What song did Demi sing on AS THE BELL RINGS?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="two" id="heartattack" value="Wannabe"> <label for="heartattack">HeartAttack</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="two" id="together" value="Fake"> <label for="together">Together</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="two" id="shadow" value="Hardcore"> <label for="shadow">Shadow</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="two" id="gotta" value="Lowkey"> <label for="gotta">Gotta Find You</label>
     </div>
    
     <div class="col three">
     <br>
     3. How did Demi celebrate her 21st birthday?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="three" id="partying" value="Fake"> <label for="partying">Partying</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="three" id="africa" value="Hardcore"> <label for="africa">Mission Trip to Africa</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="three" id="disneyland" value="Lowkey"> <label for="disneyland">Disneyland</label>
         <br><input type="radio" name="three" id="home" value="Wannabe"> <label for="home">At Home</label> 
     </div>
    
     <div class="col four">
     <br>
     4. What celebrity sent Demi flowers when she was in Rehab?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="four" id="selena" value="Lowkey"> <label for="selena">Selena</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="four" id="miley" value="Hardcore"> <label for="miley">Miley</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="four" id="taylor" value="Wannabe"> <label for="taylor">Taylor</labe> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="four" id="ashley" value="Fake"> <label for="ashley">Ashley</label> 
     </div>
    
     <div class="col five">
     <br>
     5. What substance abuse addictions did Demi struggle with?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="five" id="alcohol" value="Wannabe"> <label for="alcohol">Alcohol</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="five" id="cocaine" value="Lowkey"> <label for="cocaine">Cocaine</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="five" id="weed" value="Fake"> <label for="weed">Weed</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="five" id="all" value="Hardcore"> <label for="all">All Of The Above</label> 
     </div>
    
     <div class="col six">
     <br>
     6. What artist has Demi NOT collaborated with?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="six" id="adele" value="Hardcore"> <label for="slytherin">Adele</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="six" id="miguel" value="Lowkey"> <label for="miguel">Miguel</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="six" id="missy" value="Fake"> <label for="missy">Missy Elliot</label>
         <br><input type="radio" name="six" id="john" value="Wannabe"> <label for="john">John Mayer</label> 
     </div>
    
     <div class="col seven">
     <br>
     7. What disease does Demi Lovato struggle with?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="seven" id="lupus" value="Lowkey"> <label for="lupus">Lupus</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="seven" id="diabetes" value="Wannabe"> <label for="diabetes">Diabetes</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="seven" id="bipolar" value="Hardcore"> <label for="bipolar">Bipolar</label>
         <br><input type="radio" name="seven" id="none" value="Fake"> <label for="none">None</label> 
     </div>
    
     <div class="col eight">
     <br>
     8. What kind of shows does Demi enjoy watching?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="eight" id="reality" value="Fake"> <label for="reality">Reality Shows</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="eight" id="crime" value="Hardcore"> <label for="crime">Crime Shows</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="eight" id="sitcoms" value="Lowkey"> <label for="sitcoms">Sitcoms</label>
         <br><input type="radio" name="eight" id="game" value="Wannabe"> <label for="game">Game Shows</label>
     </div>
    
     <div class="col nine">
     <br>
     9. Which artist did Demi shade in 2016?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="nine" id="taylor" value="Lowkey"> <label for="taylor">Taylor Swift</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="nine" id="nicki" value="Wannabe"> <label for="nicki">Nicki Minaj</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="nine" id="selena" value="Fake"> <label for="selena">Selena Gomez</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="nine" id="all" value="Hardcore"> <label for="all">All of the Above</label> 
     </div>
    
     <div class="col ten">
     <br>
     10. Which celebrity friendship has Demi NOT publicly made?
     <br>
         <input type="radio" name="ten" id="jennifer" value="Fake"> <label for="jennifer">Jennifer Lopez</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="ten" id="ariana" value="Lowkey"> <label for="ariana">Ariana Grande</label>
         <br><input type="radio" name="ten" id="christina" value="Hardcore"> <label for="christina">Christina Aguilera</label> 
         <br><input type="radio" name="ten" id="iggy" value="Wannabe"> <label for="iggy">Iggy Azalea</label> 
     </div>
    
    <br><input type="button" id="quizButton" value="Get Results!"><br>
    </form>
    <p id="oneParagraph"></p>
    </body>
    <script>
    //set up a function to run when the window is loaded
    //grab the button and wait for a click
    function init() {
     var button = document.getElementById('quizButton');
     button.onclick = checkQuiz;
    }
    //get the results when the button is clicked
    function checkQuiz() {
     //confirm that the button was clicked
     //alert('Button was clicked!');
     //create a variable to store the user's house
     var one;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('one');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       one = inputs[i].value;
       alert(one);
       displayOne(one);
    /*
     var two;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('two');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       two = inputs[i].value;
       alert(two);
       displayTwo(two);
    
     var three;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('three');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       three = inputs[i].value;
       alert(three);
       displayThree(three);
    
     var four;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('four');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       four = inputs[i].value;
       alert(four);
       displayFour(four);
    
     var five;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('five');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       five = inputs[i].value;
       alert(five);
       displayFive(five);
    
     var six;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('six');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       six = inputs[i].value;
       alert(six);
       displaySix(six);
    
     var seven;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('seven');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       seven = inputs[i].value;
       alert(seven);
       displaySeven(seven);
    
     var eight;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('eight');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       eight = inputs[i].value;
       alert(eight);
       displayEight(eight);
    
     var nine;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('nine');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       nine = inputs[i].value;
       alert(nine);
       displayNine(nine);
    
     var ten;
     //get the input data as an array
     var inputs = document.getElementsByName('ten');
     //loop through all the possible inputs (the radio buttons)
     for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      //see if one of the buttons is selected
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       //if it is save the house name
       ten = inputs[i].value;
       alert(ten);
       displayTen(ten);
    */
      }
     }
     //if house hasn't been defined, no choice was picked
     /*if (!one) {
      alert('Please answer question one.');
     }*/
    }
    //display a results image for the chosen house
    function displayOne(one) {
     //make a new image object
     var image = document.createElement('img');
     //assign it CSS properties with a class
     image.className = 'one';
     //grab the paragraph to append the image to
     var source = document.getElementById('oneParagraph');
     // use a \ to indicate a ' in a string
     var text = 'You\'re a ' + one + ' Fan!';
     //pick the right image source by house using a switch statement
    switch(one) {
      case 'Fake':
       image.src = 'http://24.media.tumblr.com/acf005f7efdd37f9cde57592a80055c5/tumblr_mpqppeDWMY1sqjb9eo3_500.gif';
       break;
      case 'Wannabe':
       image.src = 'http://data3.whicdn.com/images/64130190/large.gif';
       break;
      case 'Lowkey':
       image.src = 'http://24.media.tumblr.com/d4af4200cc8ac0ba5bb0f56afec858dc/tumblr_mj4xhrhsWF1rgmvx3o1_250.gif';
       break;
      case 'Hardcore':
       image.src = 'http://media.giphy.com/media/2VnL5vdmRJfVe/giphy.gif';
       break;
      default:
       image.src = '';
    }
     //add the image to the paragraph
     source.appendChild(image);
     //append the text on a new line
     source.innerHTML += '<br>' + text;
    }
    //call the initial function when the window is loaded
    window.onload = init;
    
    </script>

<html>
```

Comment: i just updated the html code, i placed the wrong one. but it is now edited.

Comment: Hi, if you are wanting to store data you will need to use php, you can store data in a session but JS will only store data until the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

so i think what you have to do is first of all, check if the answer is true or false, you can do that by assigning your javascript for each var (one, two, three) to only 'accept' one answer.
 So the way I would do it is check if the answer is correct in the variable for the question. (You can do that by checking the id of the input). Then, if it is correct just say something simple like setting up a variable to equal 1 then whenever they get a correct answer just do: 
score += 1;

Then at the end add up all the scores:

```
if (score <= 3) {fake();}
```

then for each 'score' (fake, wannabe...), make a function. e.g.

```
function fake() { image.src =           'http://24.media.tumblr.com/acf005f7efdd37f9cde57592a80055c5/tumblr_mpqppeDWMY1sqjb9eo3_500.gif';}
```

and then the same for all the others